# How to skip specific columns in a Row copy

Tags: excel, vba

So, I'm looking for a way to skip specific columns in a row copy. I'm working with doing a bunch of loops to copy/paste from a bunch of sheets of variable sized reports and I want a way to simply skip a column or columns in a row copy since I can't just do a `entirecolumn.delete` to deal with the excess and doing a counter system might get broken. I guess what I'd like (which doesn't exist as far as I know) is something like a row copy columns 3 to 5 ignore.

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCell As Range

For Each Cell In Sheet10.Range("A:B") 
If Cell.Value Like "*Total*" Then
        Set Mastersheet = Sheet10
        Set Pastesheet = Sheet3
    Cell.EntireRow.Copy

    With Pastesheet
        Set LastCell = Pastesheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

        If Not LastCell Is Nothing Then
            LastRow = LastCell.Row
        End If

        Pastesheet.Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    End With
End If
```

Next

Comment: Is it always **ONLY** columns 3 to 5 you want to ignore? What other conditions may justify skipping a column?

Comment: @Maldred It would be something to ignore the row cells in columns 3 to 5 in some cases. Like: I want to copy the entire Row 4 save for C4 through E4.

Comment: Filter your range on columns A and B, hide columns C-E, then copy paste the visible cells using xlvisible. There are examples on SO and google.

Comment: @GMalc59 I like the idea, but I'm struggling to find an example where blanks aren't pasted over. Is there a way to stop that? So that the pasted cells shift to the left?

Comment: @George Sorry, I had to actually earn some money, I will provide you an example tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i would accomplish your task, broken-down into steps.

```
Dim rw As Range

'Step 1: Insert helper column
Columns(3).Insert

'Step 2: If any cell in columns A or B contain the word "Total", put "1" in the helper column
    For Each rw In Worksheets("Sheet10").UsedRange.Rows
        If rw.Cells(1, 1).Value Like "*Total*" Or rw.Cells(1, 2).Value Like "*Total*" Then
           rw.Cells(1, 3).Value = "1"
        End If
    Next

'Step 3: Filter using the helper column, hide the helper column and 3 other columns, copy(offset removes header row), paste to sheet3 lastrow +1
    With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="1"
        .Columns("C:F").Hidden = True
        .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlVisible).Copy Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End With

'Step 4: Clean up Sheet10, or macro will not work next time
    With Sheet10
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Columns.Hidden = False
        .Rows.Hidden = False
        .Columns(3).Delete
    End With
```